# Rank value from a column from lowest to highest

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to to something like this

Input

```
   Animal Weight
0   Cat   1.2
1   Cat   1.1
2   Cat   2.5
3   Cat   0.8
4   Dog   5.3
5   Dog   4.7
6   Dog   4.2
7   Dog   3.6
8   Dog   4.9
9   Dog   6.0
```

Output

```
   Animal Weight Position
0   Cat   1.2       2
1   Cat   1.1       3
2   Cat   2.5       1
3   Cat   0.8       4
4   Dog   5.3       2
5   Dog   4.7       4
6   Dog   4.2       5
7   Dog   3.6       6
8   Dog   4.9       3
9   Dog   6.0       1
```

Is there any pandas way to do it ?

PS: If you have any proposition to change the title i take it ! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`groupby.rank`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.rank.html) with `method='dense', ascending=False`:

```
df['Position'] = (df.groupby('Animal').rank(method='dense', ascending=False)
                    .astype(int) # optional
                  )
```

Output:

```
  Animal  Weight  Position
0    Cat     1.2         2
1    Cat     1.1         3
2    Cat     2.5         1
3    Cat     0.8         4
4    Dog     5.3         2
5    Dog     4.7         4
6    Dog     4.2         5
7    Dog     3.6         6
8    Dog     4.9         3
9    Dog     6.0         1
```